# C# Math Formula (User EXP formula)

Tags: c#, math

Making a program to help me plan out things in a game I play. (Still learning basic code)

In the game you can buy 50 HP in exchange for experience points.

The formula is: EXP per 50 HP = CurrentHP * 500.

I’d like to do a formula that takes how much Experience you have and tells you how many times you can buy 50HP. The part that confuses me is because the cost goes up each time, I’m not sure what the best formula is to accurately find out with the compounding increasing costs each time.

Comment: Consider posting to math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: This is a simple recursive function, or a loop. however you need to be very specific with what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are saying that you can buy 50 HP for (currentHP * 500) EXP, or:

```
(currentHP * 500) EXP = 50 HP;
```

I'm also assuming that this means you can only buy HP in increments of 50, otherwise the formula would reduce to:

```
(currentHP * 10) EXP = 1 HP;
```

If that's correct, you can just use a while loop that increments a variable containing the purchasable HP, and the condition of the while loop takes into account the amount of HP you've "purchased" in the formula. This basically simulates the continual purchase of HP until you don't have enough EXP anymore:

```
private static int GetMaxPurchasableHP(int EXP, int currentHP)
{
    int purchasableHP = 0;

    while (EXP >= (currentHP + purchasableHP) * 500)
    {
        purchasableHP += 50;
    }

    return purchasableHP;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that’s exactly what I meant! I think I was over thinking the thing, loop makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. There likely is a mathematic way to solve it, but I don't know it. As @AlexisOlson mentioned, you might want to post this as a math (or story) question (rather than a coding question) to [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com) if you want to explore the formula route.